# Can not Install the Web API Client Libraries

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am going through [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). I have created console app and NuGet pakage was already installed.next step is to install Micrsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Library. but this package in not available at my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to package manager and search for 'web client' it should be the first result.

Otherwise manually install via the console with:
`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 5.0.0`

nuGet Package website:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.0.0